# Jmeter - Using GET/POST with single call

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test, i need to test the same endpoint is capable of using both GET/POST http method. What is the easiest way, how i can do it without creating duplicates of the script?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can normally [parameterize](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) the [HTTP request method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) by creating a simple CSV file with the following contents:

```
method
GET
POST
```

once done you can add a [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element and set it up like:

[image]

and in your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler just use `${method}` JMeter Variable

[image]

That's it, you can now run your request and it will hit the endpoint twice using different methods:

[image]