# Jmeter - Using GET/POST with single call - While loop

Tags: jmeter

Based on the [Jmeter - Using GET/POST with single call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146240/jmeter-using-get-post-with-single-call/62156913#62156913) i tried to perform GET/POST calls with single call, solution works fine if i don't use some data source.

But, i my test, i already use csv file as data source. My current set up is like:

```
TC_name, login_id, excpecedCode
test_with_valid_login_id,2132537288,200
test_with_unknown_login_id,11111,200
test_with_known_login_id,1,200
test_with_invalide_login_id,dsddfd,400
test_with_negative_login_id,-100,400
```

[image]

[image]

And, in the csv i have 5 test cases which are driven my test.
If i try to add second csv, i am not able to perform both GET/POST operation for every single test cases.

I try to add

[image]

But, still i am not able to get 10 executions based on the 5 test cases present in the csv data config.

What is the easiest set up, so i can drive my test to run both GET/POST on the top of While loop driven by csv?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change your CSV file to include the [HTTP Request method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) along with all other parameters like:

```
TC_name, login_id, excpecedCode, method
test_with_valid_login_id,2132537288,200,GET
test_with_valid_login_id,2132537288,200,POST
test_with_unknown_login_id,11111,200,GET
test_with_unknown_login_id,11111,200,POST
test_with_known_login_id,1,200,GET
test_with_known_login_id,1,200,POST
test_with_invalide_login_id,dsddfd,400,GET
test_with_invalide_login_id,dsddfd,400,POST
test_with_negative_login_id,-100,400,GET
test_with_negative_login_id,-100,400,POST
```

If the CSV file is not something you can control you can

1. Create a simple text file called `methods.txt` in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation looking like:

   ```
   GET
   POST
   ```
2. Put the request(s) you want to repeat under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with 2 Loops
3. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) instead of `${method}` in the HTTP Request sampler:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new File('methods.txt').readLines().get(vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int),)}
   ```